# Azure notification hub - migration from GCM to FCM

Tags: azure, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have some questions about migration to FCM. We’ve got an information from google about final term to migrate to FCM.
Google said that we have about many requests to GCM. Actually we have an authorization in azure notification hub via FCM token.
I was sure that when we started to use FCM token we also started to use FCM, not GCM.
So, I have two questions about migration to FCM.

1. Should I change arm configuration, I have a configuration as below.

   `{ "gcmCredential": { "properties": { "googleApiKey": "[parameters('apiKey')]" } }`
2. We are using azure notification hub only by our backend systems via rest api. Endpoint for direct push send, have a header 'Content-Type' which we set to 'GCM'. Should we change this value to FCM?

Could you please give me recommendation what I need to do, to switch GCM to FCM.

Comment: I've also just received the same email. My application has had the FCM key registered in Azure, and been using FCM in the Android app, for some time. What version of the Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs Nuget are you using? I'm using 1.0.5 and so well due an upgrade - I assume that's the cause in my case, as no doubt it's calling the GCM endpoints still.

Comment: I received the same email and this project has never used GCM.  Besides that email, I haven't found a way to check the message counts by endpoint to see if it has been migrated.

Comment: @DaveU As i said we are using notification hub via rest api. We don't have any nuget packages, actually we are using one simple api endpoint to send direct notification. Here you have documentation for rest api [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt608572(v%3dazure.100))

Comment: Ah yes, apologies @HubertPietruczuk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Notification Hubs team has been working on our internal transition to FCM endpoints. There should be no action required from customers. I’ll answer your questions to the best of my knowledge.

1. ARM configuration should also remain unchanged. We left the terminology as it was to not make a breaking change. Ultimately, Google has documented they will continue to support GCM keys and FCM keys indefinitely.
2. Please continue to use `GCM` as the content-type header. We will continue to honor it, along with the normal GCM notification schema and then internally we will send it to FCM through their compatibility API.

Comment: I got an information from microsoft support that when i use rest api i will change 'ServiceBusNotification-Format’ header value from GCM to FCM.

Answer (score 0):

We got the same emails. From the client side we are definitely using FCM.

We have entered the FCM keys in to the hub settings in the Azure console.

It appears that ANH itself is sending to GCM when you call the Service Class from the backend.

Can this be confirmed?  And if is the case; when will this be updated?

Cheers,

Roy